# How do I make a caller see the trait implementation of a method?

Tags: rust, traits

With the code:

```
trait Msg {
    fn apply_to_state(&self, state: &mut State);
}

trait ApplicableToStateOne: Msg {
    fn apply_to_state(&self, state: &mut State) {
        match state {
            State::StateOne(s) => {
                self.apply_to_state_one(s) 
            }
            _ => {
                //TODO: return an error
            }
        }
    }
    fn apply_to_state_one(&self, state_one: &mut StateOne);
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct MsgA {
    pub field_a: u8,
}

impl Msg for MsgA {}
impl ApplicableToStateOne for MsgA {
    fn apply_to_state_one(&self, state_one: &mut StateOne) {
        state_one.one_special += 31; // just a mutability test
    }
}

// this is a stub for receiving different kinds of messages from the network
fn recv() -> Box<dyn Msg> {
    Box::new(MsgA { field_a: 42 })
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = State::StateOne(StateOne { common: 0, one_special: 1 });
    for _ in 0..100 { // this would be loop, but that makes the playground timeout
        let incoming = recv(); // this would block
        incoming.apply_to_state(&mut state)
    }
}
```

( playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c89a2bbc765380fc002864e2be80e55 )

the compiler complains:

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `apply_to_state`
  --> src/bin/sandbox6.rs:83:1
   |
2  |     fn apply_to_state(&self, state: &mut State);
   |     -------------------------------------------- `apply_to_state` from trait
...
83 | impl Msg for MsgA {}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `apply_to_state` in implementation
```

In my (obviously deficient) understanding, I would have expected the `trait ApplicableToStateOne` implementation of `apply_to_state` to be called.

How can I make this happen?

---

Update:

More abstractly, this question is about:

1. receiving a boxed supertrait object from the network, then
2. finding out which subtrait it has, and finally
3. calling a method appropriate for the subtrait (perhaps through the supertrait in some way).

This can all be done, rather verbosely, using enums instead of traits, but that adds a hierarchy of enums.

Having a hierarchy of enums is bad because:

- it adds unnecessary bytes to the serialisation, and because
- there can be only one such hierarchy, which prevents classification of messages in any other way.

Comment: Well, you did not implemented the method for `Msg`.  You cannot expect the other implementation to be called. The method is linked to the trait completely, and the compiler need to know which one of them will you be calling.

Comment: @Netwave I'm trying to avoid writing identical `apply_to_state` methods for dozens of structs which all implement `Msg`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Rust has very limited OO features. One thing it does not support is overriding methods, which is what you're trying to do in your trait `ApplicableToStateOne`, where you're trying to override the method defined in trait `Msg`. The methods in both traits have the same name, but one is not overriding the other. So, it's not going to work this way.

Comment: @fadedbee, but you are indeed doing it right? since you are implementing the method for other trait. You can try to use that trait directly in the `Msg` one (as implementing the method in the trait).

Comment: @Netwave Sorry, I haven't understood your last comment.  Is there a way of writing the `apply_to_state` method only three times for a large number of structs of three `Msg` "subtypes" `ApplicateToStateOne`, `ApplicableToStateTwo` and `ApplicableToCommonState`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generic to implement `Msg` for everything that implements `ApplicableToStateOne`:

```
struct State {}

trait Msg {
    fn apply_to_state(&self, state: &mut State);
}

trait ApplicableToStateOne: Msg {
    fn apply_to_state_one(&self, state: &mut State) {
        todo!();
    }
}

impl<T: ApplicableToStateOne> Msg for T {
    fn apply_to_state(&self, state: &mut State) {
        self.apply_to_state_one (state);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct MsgA {
    pub field_a: u8,
}

impl ApplicableToStateOne for MsgA {}
// No need to implement Msg explicitly for MsgA
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a338eae012ec586f83dae120af562d0a)

Comment: Exatly, this is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, it will take me some time to understand `impl<T: ApplicableToStateOne> Msg for T`.  This looks like an extremely powerful mechanism for getting around the lack of inheritance.

Comment: The problem here is that im not sure if it will be allowed for more than a default trait. Im curious on how to do it actually: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fdea3ea99b9410ef1140c2dc8486a9b7

Comment: There's a problem.  Once I define `impl<T: ApplicableToStateTwo> Msg for T {` I get `conflicting implementations of trait 'Msg'`.

Comment: @Netwave and Jmb Sorry, I have to go now.  Thanks for all your help, I'll check later today.

Comment: @fadedbee offtopic comment, but it's a **bliss** of not having inheritance

Comment: @Netwave and Jmb - I've added a clarifying update to the question.

Comment: You need to remove the `impl Msg for MsgA` (it gets added automatically since `MsgA` implements `ApplicableToStateTwo`).

Comment: @AlexLarionov I've used OO in Java/C++ off and on for 25 years and have found inheritance problematic in many ways.  On the other hand, I haven't yet discovered how to avoid repeated identical function definitions in Rust, or whether that's even possible.

Comment: @fadedbee I haven't ever built a huge code base in Rust (or in anything else), but I've never seen this as a limitation. In most of the cases all I need is composition + forwarding of only a few methods as a public API for this new extension (not all of the methods). If it really bothers you to forward dozens of methods, then `into_inner() -> BaseStruct` pattern is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Think of each of the methods to be linked to the `Trait` instead of the object itself.
Check this simpler example:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str;
}

trait FooPrime {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str;
}

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
        "foo"
    }
}

impl FooPrime for Bar {
  fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
        "foo prime"
    }  
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar{};
    println!("{} : {}", bar.foo(), bar.foo());
}
```

When compiling we get the following error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> src/main.rs:25:29
   |
25 |     println!("{} : {}", bar.foo(), bar.foo());
   |                             ^^^ multiple `foo` found
   |
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `Foo` for the type `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `FooPrime` for the type `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:18:3
   |
18 |   fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #1
   |
25 |     println!("{} : {}", Foo::foo(&bar), bar.foo());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #2
   |
25 |     println!("{} : {}", FooPrime::foo(&bar), bar.foo());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> src/main.rs:25:40
   |
25 |     println!("{} : {}", bar.foo(), bar.foo());
   |                                        ^^^ multiple `foo` found
   |
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `Foo` for the type `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `FooPrime` for the type `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:18:3
   |
18 |   fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #1
   |
25 |     println!("{} : {}", bar.foo(), Foo::foo(&bar));
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #2
   |
25 |     println!("{} : {}", bar.foo(), FooPrime::foo(&bar));
```

We need to **explicitly tell the compiler which method to use**:

```rust
fn main() {
    let bar = Bar{};
    println!("{} : {}", Foo::foo(&bar), FooPrime::foo(&bar));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e6a3938712992c5d413d14ffed2becd)

For the same reason in your code the method for the other trait is not used, since it is not part of the previous trait.
Here is a [link to the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name)

You may want to use the [supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) functionality for creating a default impl of another trait based on the "parent" one:

```rust
trait FooPrime : Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
        Foo::foo(self)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f595cd276d9502cd73d6493265ad20a6)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I understand disambiguation.  What I don't understand is how I can implement `apply_to_state` only three times for a large number of structs of three `Msg` "subtypes" `ApplicateToStateOne`, `ApplicableToStateTwo` and `ApplicableToCommonState`.

Comment: @fadedbee, check the latest addition to the answer. Maybe you can use a supertrait for composing the states.

Comment: Apologies, I've just realised that there is an ambiguity issue here, as Rust does not have trait inheritance.  The question in my previous comment stands.

Comment: I've realised that I want a "backwards" supertrait.  I want a common interface to three diifferent traits.  Can Rust do this?

Comment: @fededbee. I was checking your playground again and I have the feeling you are complicating things. I'll try to spend a bit more time and try to refactor it so it works.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.  I have only three `Applicable` types but many `Msg` structs which implement one of those.